# What's the best way to display options within options within options in an onboarding process?

Tags: onboarding, many-options

I am creating an onboarding process where the admin dictates requirements for it's members.

They start by selecting from a list of identifiers

**[ ] Meat
[ ] Poultry
[ ] Seafood
[ ] Produce**

Then they go into each identifier they select and pick options

*Meat:*

**[ ] Steak 
[ ] Hamburger 
[ ] Hot dogs**

Then they go into each option and pick more options

*Steak:*

**[ ] Filet Mignon
[ ] NY Strip
[ ] Ribeye**

Now they will need to go back through this process for possibly Poultry, Seafood and Produce.

What's the best way to do this? What is this called?

Comment: Have you considered a [cascading list](http://designinginterfaces.com/firstedition/index.php?page=Cascading_Lists) with checkboxes on the leaf nodes?

Comment: I have! It's still an option on the table. Thanks!

Comment: As presented this question has gone beyond the 'goal' or 'user story' level of abstraction and has introduced a quite limited scope, which excludes a number of potential design options.  e.g. Impossible to design a UI where user selects "NY Strip" directly?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a name for this iterative process but I would clearly identify where the user is. For example a breadcrumb can show where the user is in the process (first time through the iteration as well as subsequent times through).

Identifier > Sub-identifier > Sub-sub-identifier

I would also consider showing the completed Categories. For example (and don't pay attention to my wording)

"You have completed:
MEAT"

If complex iterations are commonplace (and non-sequential) and if the staff are often called away from the on-boarding task and come back to it later then I would consider showing a more in depth display of what has been done as well as the available options. Something along the line of:

YOU HAVE COMPLETED

[Main Category Label]

AAA

BBB

CCC

**Meat**

DDD

**Poultry**

Produce

Seafood

Comment: I like this option too! I am going to wireframe both and see what makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an old classic tree for this kind of need. If you want to go back and forth it seems a not so bad idea.
For limited space and/or more step by step approach you can go to a wizard like interface.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f10yWl.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>